# Is there any option to get duration of GitLab's pipeline using curl/python requests?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, pipeline, duration, gitlab-api

I'm trying to get duration of GitLab's pipeline. My GitLab version is 12.10. I can get status of pipeline :

```
{
    "id": 7475,
    "sha": "someid",
    "ref": "Someref",
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:17.807Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:36.071Z",
    "web_url": "https://git.somedomain.net/infra/some_project/pipelines/7475",
    "before_sha": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "tag": false,
    "yaml_errors": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 85,
        "name": "some.name",
        "username": "some.name",
        "state": "active",
        "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/someid?s=80&d=identicon",
        "web_url": "https://git.somedomain.net/some.name"
    },
    "started_at": null,
    "finished_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:36.070Z",
    "committed_at": null,
    "duration": null,
    "coverage": null,
    "detailed_status": {
        "icon": "status_success",
        "text": "passed",
        "label": "passed",
        "group": "success",
        "tooltip": "passed",
        "has_details": false,
        "details_path": "/infra/some_project/pipelines/7475",
        "illustration": null,
        "favicon": "/assets/ci_favicons/favicon_status_success-8451333011eee8ce9f2ab25dc487fe24a8758c694827a582f17f42b0a90446a2.png"
    }
}
```

Is there any option to get pipeline duration?  or, how to get duration as difference between `"finished_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:36.070Z"` and `"created_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:17.807Z"` in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of values in the status dict which can be pre-defined in your code, e.g.:

```
false = False
null = None
```

Then you can do:

```
status = { "id": 7475, "sha": "someid", "ref": "Someref", "status": "success", "created_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:17.807Z", "updated_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:36.071Z", "web_url": "https://git.somedomain.net/infra/some_project/pipelines/7475", "before_sha": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "tag": false, "yaml_errors": null, "user": { "id": 85, "name": "some.name", "username": "some.name", "state": "active", "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/someid?s=80&d=identicon", "web_url": "https://git.somedomain.net/some.name" }, "started_at": null, "finished_at": "2021-04-28T12:07:36.070Z", "committed_at": null, "duration": null, "coverage": null, "detailed_status": { "icon": "status_success", "text": "passed", "label": "passed", "group": "success", "tooltip": "passed", "has_details": false, "details_path": "/infra/some_project/pipelines/7475", "illustration": null, "favicon": "/assets/ci_favicons/favicon_status_success-8451333011eee8ce9f2ab25dc487fe24a8758c694827a582f17f42b0a90446a2.png" } }
```

Then use the `datetime` module to:

1. convert strings to datetime objects (reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), and
2. perform your duration calculation.

```
import datetime as dt

format_str = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
created_at = dt.datetime.strptime(status['created_at'],format_str)
finished_at = dt.datetime.strptime(status['finished_at'],format_str)

duration = finished_at - created_at
```

Result:

```
In [24]: duration
Out[24]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=18, microseconds=263000)
```

Comment: @ŠtefanSedmák: you're welcome :) Best wishes with the rest of your project!